# raspberry / docker swarm / traefik / portainer and no HTTPS

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-swarm, traefik

I spent the last 3 days trying to use traefik for HTTPS, load balancer, and to connect portainer and other docker containers in swarm mode. It is a home-server cluster made with 4 raspberrys, and what I want is the SSL auto-certificate function, and the HTTP to HTTPS redirection. For that purpose I've created a traefik.toml file:

```
    logLevel = "DEBUG"
    defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

    [web]

    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.http]
      address = ":80"
            [entryPoints.http.redirect]
            entryPoint = "https"
      [entryPoints.https]
      address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]

    [acme]
      email = "xxx@xxx.com"
      storage = "acme.json"
      entryPoint = "https"
      OnHostRule = true

    [acme.httpChallenge]
      entryPoint = "http"

    [docker]
      domain = "traefik" #<---- WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?
      watch = true
      swarmmode = true
```

I don't know what should I write in the DOMAIN variable. I use NoIP as my dynamic DNS provider. Should I write the domain I get from them? and that should work inside my network? i.e. accesing from a computer inside my network with: 192.168.11.100

And I also have a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - "--api"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS"
      - "--defaultentrypoints=http,https"
      - "--acme"
      - "--acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
      - "--acme.entryPoint=https"
      - "--acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http"
      - "--acme.onHostRule=true"
      - "--acme.onDemand=false"
      - "--acme.email=xxx@xxx.com"
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmMode"
      - "--docker.domain=traefik.localhost" <- WHAT SHOULD I PUT IN HERE??
      - "--docker.watch"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /mnt/traefik/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
    networks:
      - appnet
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
networks:
  appnet:
    external: true
```

Deploy the stack, then I write in firefox in another computer 192.168.11.100, and I can see the "Welcome to nginx page". No HTTPS by the way. Try 192.168.11.100:8080 for the traefik dashboard. It is there, but again only HTTP.

If I deploy portainer, looks like it connects with traefik (at least appear in the dashboard), but again only HTTP.

Here's the logs for the traefik container after deploying portainer:

```
time="2019-02-19T11:32:52Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"portainer.com\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:portainer.com\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [portainer.com]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[portainer.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from http://portainer.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eDN0Z2VJRzuZm9wiAbar1BOVHLPJ5qPYKBpwfuJOtdY: \"<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset=\\\"utf-8\\\"><meta http-equiv=\\\"x-ua-compatible\\\" content=\\\"ie=edge\\\"><meta name=\\\"viewport\\\" cont\", url: \n"
time="2019-02-19T11:33:15Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"portainer.com\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:portainer.com\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [portainer.com]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[portainer.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from http://portainer.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/Of6CWm4zvCdPo0BFPTxapEVXPU-qf7hhl1f6NCUTmQw: \"<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset=\\\"utf-8\\\"><meta http-equiv=\\\"x-ua-compatible\\\" content=\\\"ie=edge\\\"><meta name=\\\"viewport\\\" cont\", url: \n"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you every find a solution?